# install 32bit or 64 for older pc

Tags: windows, system-installation, 64-bit, 32-bit

I got a hp/compaq presario c751nr, this laptop is a older computer with 2gb of ram i think it has a 64 bit processor but i believe it came with 32 bit vista,correct me if im wrong. im a tech savy linux newbie (coming from windows). what is a good distro for me, should i get the 32 or 64 bit version.

Answer (score -1):

In Windows. I haven't notice a great advantage in day to day equipment use 64 bits or 32  unless some software requires it

Server or unix based systems have a great advantage in speed. you can notice it, but really at windows I never notice it ...

Ofcourse 64 bit handle more memory but even windows xp can handle 2gb of memory.

Rumors say that windows 8 requires even less than 7 and I believe it too.

All this as my very personal experience. notice that i say day to day.. and not a professional equipment although probably that presario will not fit anyway.

On linux please give a try to the latest LTS ubuntu or derivatives as you are new user.
If you processor handle 64 bit instructions then use it.

remember processor and system and at least many unix distros are capable to handle 32 when you OS are 64... so you will be able to use 32 and 64 bits softwares within a 64 bits OS.

Answer (score -2):

Try using Mint Linux or Xubuntu. Both of them work great on slow or old computers.
Go with 32bit version. That would be stable.